# How to display print label with php code

Tags: php

i want a condtion to make a print label visible
if $data_common[$datacntr]['SKU'] = something

```
 echo <a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open(\'printLabel.php?OrderID=' . $orderId . '& Name=' . $Name . '&ShippingAddress=' . $ShippingAddress . '& AddressLine1=' . $AddressLine1 . ' &AddressLine2=' . $AddressLine2 . '&AddressLine3=' . $AddressLine3 . '&City=' . $City . '&County=' . $County . '&District=' . $District . '&StateOrRegion=' . $StateOrRegion . '&PostalCode=' . $PostalCode . '&Phone=' . $Phone . '&platform=' . $platform . '\',\'Popup\',\'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=700,height=600,left=430,top=23\'); return false;"><img src="images/printLabel.png" alt="Print Lable"></a></td>
```

else nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if (isset($data_common[$datacntr]['SKU']) && $data_common[$datacntr]['SKU'] == "something") : ?>
     <?php echo '<a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open(\'printLabel.php?OrderID=' . $orderId . '& Name=' . $Name . '&ShippingAddress=' . $ShippingAddress . '& AddressLine1=' . $AddressLine1 . ' &AddressLine2=' . $AddressLine2 . '&AddressLine3=' . $AddressLine3 . '&City=' . $City . '&County=' . $County . '&District=' . $District . '&StateOrRegion=' . $StateOrRegion . '&PostalCode=' . $PostalCode . '&Phone=' . $Phone . '&platform=' . $platform . '\',\'Popup\',\'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=700,height=600,left=430,top=23\'); return false;"><img src="images/printLabel.png" alt="Print Lable"></a>' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The first condition in the if statement will check if this `$data_common[$datacntr]['SKU']` key exists. The second is if it equals to something (change "something" to your value).

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Answer (score 1):

```
$label= (isset($data_common[$datacntr]['SKU']) && !empty($data_common[$datacntr]['SKU']))?'YOuR LABEL CODE':'';

echo $label;
```